# Explicitly tracking pure actions in a side-effecting monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

Generally there is a safe way to `extract` from a monadic action when it is the result of a `pure`/`return` call. E.g. `unsafePerformIO (pure 42)` will not effect the world. As long as I *only* use these monadic operations I am safe in the pure fragment.

I am interested in a disciplined way of generalizing this notion. My first idea was to use a `newtype` of `Either` and injections `Left` for pure values and `Right` when it is not provably pure. Writing the monad instance was reasonably simple. I could even make it a monad transformer.
I am aware of the free monad (transformer) construction, too.

What is the expert's opinion on which way I should go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `Applicative`s, there's [`Lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Lift.html) from the `transformers` package.

`Lift` adds an explicitly pure computation to an already existing `Applicative`, and provides "optimized" implementations for `<*>` for cases when one or both of the arguments are explicitly pure.

This can be useful when the `<*>` operation of the base `Applicative` is expensive in some way. For example, consider the useful [`Concurrently`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.0.1.6/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#t:Concurrently) applicative from `Control.Concurrent.Async` that runs two `IO` actions in parallel by forking threads.

Executing something like

```
pure (+) <*> pure 5 <*> Other (Concurrently (return 5)) :: Lift Concurrently Int
```

won't fork any threads.

As for the `Monad` instance, something like this could work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype Foo a = Foo { getFoo :: Lift IO a } deriving (Functor, Applicative)      

instance Monad Foo where
    return = pure
    (Foo m) >>= k = case m of
        Pure a -> k a 
        Other m -> Foo (Other (m >>= unLift . getFoo . k))
```

I wonder why `Lift` doesn't already have something like this instance.

Comment: The implementation of the (>>) operator can also be optimized in knowledge of the first action being pure.

Answer (score 2):

As @danidiaz wrote, for applicative functors, there already is `Lift`. However, monads (unlike applicative functors) don't compose, so for this it'll be necessary to create a monad transformer:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans

data Impure m a = Pure a | Impure (m a)

instance (Monad m) => Monad (Impure m) where
    return = Pure
    (Pure x) >>= f = f x
    (Impure k) >>= f = Impure $ k >>= \x -> case f x of
                                                Pure y -> return y
                                                Impure l -> l

instance MonadTrans Impure where
    lift = Impure
```